# test Junit deleteById doesn't pass if id is not present

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jpa, junit

I'm doing some junit tests to improve my application. One of these, tests the deletion of a single raw *(indicated by an id as primary key)* if present, and this works fine. Now I'm testing how my application behave if I want to delete an id Not present in my database.

What I expect is that my test passes with 0 rows affected, but he doesn't pass giving me this error:

> No class com.package1.package2.package3.entities.className entity with id 326L exists!

Some advice?

Comment: add code that gives error

Comment: jpa auto-generates query. I'm only calling public void deleteById(id). What i'm expecting is something like sql query if delete doesn't find data to delete. Simply 0 rows affected by delete comand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deleteById()` from `CrudRepository` firstly tries to find entity by `Id`.

In case no entity is found it throws *exception;* You can have your own repository and declare `deleteAllByIdIn()` method which takes collection of ids as argument and ORM will create its implementation for you.

This way you should not get any exceptions even if entities with such ids were not present. Or you can always make a native SQL query that deletes the row in DB by id.

Comment: Just tried to write native query. Now is giving this: 
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.

Btw using the native query to delete an existing id, the query works.

Comment: Did you use repository to make a native query? If so you may have forgotten to put @Modifying annotation

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

The method should be :

```java
    @Query (your query, nativeQuery=true)

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void DeleteById(@Param(id) Long id)
```